# INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, duplicates, key

I'm trying to import some data from a MS-Access file to my SQL Server database. I keep getting primary key errors because some of the data overlaps. Therefore I tried using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as well as `INSERT IGNORE`. Both seem to be unknown to my SQL Server (running 2008 R2) as I get syntax errors. Do I need some add-on library or is `INSERT IGNORE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY` not usable when inserting with a select query to .mdb? Here's the code snippet:

```
INSERT INTO XCManager.XC_DATA1 (STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, ORIG_VALUE, ED_VALUE, SOURCE) 
    SELECT STATION_ID, SENSORNAME, TIME_TAG, ORIG_VALUE, ED_VALUE, SOURCE 
    FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=H:\OPERATIONS & MAINTENANCE SECTION\Modeling & Gauging\PCBase2\PCBASE2 Files.mdb')...RUMN3 

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE STATION_ID=STATION_ID
```

Here's the parsing result:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: Can you change the Sql Server schema?

Comment: Is there a specific permission or property that I should be looking for in the schema that would allow use of INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does not support `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE`. That syntax is specific to MySQL.

If you had looked up the `INSERT` statement in the [SQL Server manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) you would have seen that.

You need to use the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement in order to update or insert.

> when inserting with a select query to .mdb

I don't understand that part. If you have SQL Server you are not "*inserting into a .mdb*".
Are you maybe running MS Access instead? In that case the `MERGE` will not work either as far as I know (you would need to check the manual for MS Access for an equivalent statement)

Comment: Thanks I will try MERGE. In answer to your question, no I am not inserting into a .mdb. I meant the SELECT query is selecting data from my .mdb file for import into SQL SERVER.

Comment: Then MERGE won't work. If I'm not mistaken, MERGE will not across databases.

Comment: Hmmm. So there's nothing that would allow me to insert data from .mdb but skip/ignore duplicates? I find I can't disable the primary keys as Jani suggested, which is probably for the best.

Comment: I think the best method would be to copy the data into a temporary table in SQL Server, then use the MERGE statement to get the rows into the real table.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this got resolved, but one way to accomplish "insert ignore" in sql server is to check the "ignore duplicates" box when creating a unique index on a set of columns for a table. When you do this, SQLServer will not throw an exception, just a warning, so if you bulk insert with an index like this, then it will ignore the dupes for you.
The trouble with this is, if you have a TON of rows (10s of millions or more) having an index on the table as you bulk insert will be slower.