# SQL Server Insert with out duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with millions of records SQL DB. I want to insert a record if new one is not a duplicate record. But I dont want to check whether duplicate record exists. Is there any way to insert directly and if duplicate record exists just ignore the new insert?

Comment: check MERGE statement: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solutions for INSERT OR UPDATE on SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server)

Comment: And also others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638185/insert-into-ignore-duplicates-that-are-not-the-primary-key, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854997/insert-ignore-and-on-duplicate-key-update-not-working-in-sql-server-2008-r2, etc.

Comment: Either use MERGE statement or INSERT... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: How will you know if the record is duplicate without checking? All solutions posted by others in comments, will check if the record exists.

Comment: LEFT Join with the table?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve what you want by applying a [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on the table and specifying `IGNORE_DUP_KEY ON`:

> Specifies the error response when an insert operation attempts to insert duplicate key values into a unique index. The `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option applies only to insert operations after the index is created or rebuilt. The option has no effect when executing `CREATE INDEX`, `ALTER INDEX`, or `UPDATE`. The default is `OFF`.
>
> ON
>
> A warning message will occur when duplicate key values are inserted into a unique index. Only the rows violating the uniqueness constraint will fail.

So the insert will succeed for new unique rows, but you can't avoid the warning message.

---

You would create this index across all columns by which you're defining uniqueness/duplicates - which may or may not be all columns in the table - you haven't given us a definition to work from.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting record from a **`Table`**

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE_NAME
(.....)
SELECT
(.....)
FROM TABLE_NAME T1
INNER JOIN INSERT_TABLE_NAME T2
ON T1.COLUMN_NAME1<>T2.COLUMN_NAME1
OR T1.COLUMN_NAME2<>T2.COLUMN_NAME2
OR ...
```

If you are inserting record by **`values`**

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE_NAME
(.....)
VALUES
(.....)
WHERE 
ON VALUE1<>T2.COLUMN_NAME1
OR VALUE2<>T2.COLUMN_NAME2
```

My solution is only suitable when Column in you table are in **reasonable number**.

Ofcouse @Damien_The_Unbeliever have given a better solution. But you can't implement it After some point.